# #2002 - Connection refused — The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured)

Tags: xampp

My phpmyadmin showing this error, I am working on Ubuntu OS:

> ## 2002 - Connection refused — The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured)
>
> mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused
>
> Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed
>
> mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused

This problem is occurred on Ubuntu, I tried all previous stack overflow answers, but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: check your local socket configuration. This is configured in /etc/mysql/my.cnf

Comment: It doesn't resolved my issue, so I reinstall the xampp for Ubuntu OS. Now it's work fine but I  didn't understand why this problem occurred.

Answer (score 0):

I faced that similar problem using **lamp** , check if you may have more than two mysql path like in

Find all the other `mysql` installed in your system

```
`whereis mysql`

`mysql: /opt/lampp/bin/mysql /opt/lampp/bin/mysql.server /usr/share/man/man1/mysql.1.gz`
```

Now if in you're system two mysql if overlapping then remove others and keep only one mysql installed by lamp

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql
```

Here is the link i found for apache2 i did the same with mysql and it's working
http://xmodulo.com/how-to-uninstall-and-remove-apache2-on-ubuntu-debian.html

Finally stop all the mysql existing service running

```
sudo service mysql stop
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```